# SQL Group By and Min in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, min

I have the following SQL in MySQL DB:

```
select code, distance from locations;
```

The output is below:

```
CODE    DISTANCE            LOCATION
106     386.895834130068    New York, NY
80      2116.6747774121     Washington, DC
80      2117.61925131453    Alexandria, VA
106     2563.46708627407    Charlotte, NC
106     2030.5845606766     Atalanta, GA
```

I want to be able to just get a single code and the closest distance. So I want it to return this:

```
CODE    DISTANCE            LOCATION
106     386.895834130068    New York, NY
80      2116.6747774121     Washington, DC
```

I originally had something like this:

```
SELECT code, min(distance), location
GROUP BY code
HAVING distance > 0 
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

Comment: Repeated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683712/sql-group-by-and-min

Comment: really  ? select code, distance from locations; showed 
that output ?

Comment: @hussainnaghri, no idea what you're saying

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT code, min(distance), location
GROUP BY code,location
  HAVING distance =min(distance)
```

Comment: what if 2 codes have the exact same location, as i need all codes too?

Comment: This will lead to error. You need to include distinace in group by clause which will give different result

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select L.* from (
    SELECT code, min(distance) as min_distance 
    from places
    GROUP BY code)a
join places L
on L.CODE=a.CODE
and L.DISTANCE=a.min_distance
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT code, distance, location
FROM locations 
GROUP BY code 
HAVING distance > 0

ORDER BY distance ASC 
LIMIT 1`

Comment: nope this doesn't work, you can still get locations that don't match the min distance because of the group by